# Oracle how to alias a column that's a computed atribute in inner select statement

Tags: oracle

Here's a SQL statement that works perfectly in Transact-sql

```
SELECT a.Account_ID, a.First_Name, a.Last_Name, m.number
FROM Account a,
(SELECT R_Account_ID, COUNT(Notification_ID) AS number
FROM Rcv_Send_Event_Notf 
GROUP BY R_Account_ID) m
WHERE a.Account_ID = m.R_Account_ID
```

But it does not in Oracle. It is complaining about `m.number` in out most select statement. I believe also because of AS `number` in the 3rd line.

> invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification...

Is there a different way to **alias** a column in Oracle?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Hmm. A simplified example works for me: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4f818/2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Number` is a keyword in Oracle, so you can't use it as an alias without using double quotes. Most would advise against using it as an alias, period.

```
> select d.number from (select sysdate as number from dual) d

Error starting at line 3 in command:
select d.number from (select sysdate as number from dual) d
Error at Command Line:3 Column:9
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
01747. 00000 -  "invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification"

> select d.number from (select sysdate as "number" from dual) d

Error starting at line 2 in command:
select d.number from (select sysdate as "number" from dual) d
Error at Command Line:2 Column:9
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
01747. 00000 -  "invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification"

> select d."number" from (select sysdate as "number" from dual) d
number                    
------------------------- 
07-MAY-12 12:32:28 PM
```

Comment: That's the reason. Number is a keyword in oracle. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If I didn't miss something, you could make the same with

```
select a.account_ID, a.First_Name, a.Last_Name, count(*)
from Account a
inner join RCV_Send_Event_Notf m on a.Account_Id = m.R_Account_Id
Group by a.account_Id, a.First_Name, a.Last_Name;
```

Comment: I thank you for the suggestion. But we're not supposed to have learn that yet in class. Lol!

Answer (score 1):

Oracle may not be liking the name "number" as it's a keyword. I "boiled down" the query and renamed "number" and it appears to work

```
SELECT m.number_col
FROM dual a,
(SELECT   123 AS number_col
FROM dual ) m
```

You could also use a WITH clause:

```
 WITH m AS
(SELECT  sysdate  as number_col
FROM dual )
SELECT m.number_col
FROM dual a, m
```